# Express - Using .find with req.query returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to preform a search using mongo and express. I'm having a weird issue where if I pass a value from a query string to .find, it returns null. However if I pass the same value hardcoded it works just fine.

For example

This works just fine:

```
const property = await Property.find({ county: 'kildare'});
```

This doesn't work:

```
 const property = await Property.find({ county: req.query.county});
```

If I console.log `req.query.county` when hitting the method on the following route `http://localhost:7777/property/search?county=kildare` I get a value of kildare.

I really don't get what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Try trimming your query string to avoid spaces or any undesired characters:

```
const property = await Property.find({ county: req.query.county.trim()});
```